# Having issues with Chrome On Android OS with function not running onload

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome

So Im making a POS print solution for my andorid phone to print to a blue tooth printer.   Have evreything working fine, but want to have it auto print on page load instead of having to click on the print button i made.

```
<HTML>
 <script  type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.js"></script>  
 <script>


function sendToQuickPrinterChrome(){
   var commandsToPrint =
                "<CENTER><LOGO2>" +
                "<BOLD><CENTER><BIG> SAINT JIMMY'S COFFEE <BR>" +
                "<CENTER>Inventory Count<BR>" +
                "<CENTER>2019-01-15<BR>" +
                "<CENTER>416-xxx-xxxx<BR>" +
                "<CENTER>E-mail@email.com<BR>" +
                "<CENTER>Receipt #:002- 15-0005852<BR>" +
                "<CENTER>Store:Test Store<BR>" +
                "----------------------------------------------------------------\n" +
                "Flavour                               BoxCount  OpenPods  Added\n" +
                "Amaretto Almond                              5         4      0\n" +
                "Bavarian Chocolate                           6         2      0\n" +
                "Chocolate Raspberry                          5         2      0\n" +
                "Coconut Cream                                5         7      0\n" +
                "Cognac                                       2         3      0\n" +
                "Dark Roast                                   0         0     10\n" +
                "Decaf                                        5        12      0\n" +
                "Earl Grey Tea                                6         5      0\n" +
                "French Caramel                               5         8      0\n" +
                "French Vanilla                               4         8      0\n" +
                "Green Tea                                    6         1      0\n" +
                "Hazelnut                                     4         1      0\n" +
                "Holiday Flavours                             0         0      0\n" +
                "Hot Chocolate                                0        12      7\n" +
                "Irish Whisky & Cream                         4         3      0\n" +
                "Jamaican Me Crazy                            4        13      0\n" +
                "Light Roast                                  5         5      0\n" +
                "Medium Roast                                 0         0     10\n" +
                "Orange Pekoe Tea                             1        13      5\n" +
                "Peppermint Tea                               5        11      0\n" +
                "Pumpkin Spice                                0         2      0\n" +
                "Tiramisu                                     2         3      0\n" +
                "----------------------------------------------------------------\n" +
                "Total:                                      74       115     32<br>\n" +
                "Previous Count:;;1452\n" +
                "Current Count:;;1003\n" +
                "Total Pods Sold:;;449\n" +
                "Unit Price:;;$1.04\n" +
                "Total Charge:;;$466.96\n" +
                "<BR>\n" +
                "<BR>\n" +
                "<CUT>\n";
var textEncoded = encodeURI(commandsToPrint);
    window.location.href="intent://"+textEncoded+"#Intent;scheme=quickprinter;package=pe.diegoveloper.printerserverapp;end;";
}
$( document ).ready(function() {
    sendToQuickPrinterChrome();   
 //  console.log( "ready!" );

});
</script>


<a onclick="sendToQuickPrinterChrome();">
    <br>Print Button</a>

</HTML>
```

So my Print Button works just fine.
If I use FireFox on Android it prints when the page is loaded automatically just fine,  but if I use Chrome it does not launch the function on load and i can't figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

That will not work at the Chrome Browser or in some other Android Browser's like Samsung Internet. It's a security feature and it protects user from spam. You couldn't realize it without clicking at a button. I hope it's not a big problem for you but it's not possible.

Comment: I added an alert("test"); to the start of my function, and i get the alert, seems to be an issue with the window.location.href=  part no triggering.  I even added a Jquery event to click my button for me, and again it will trigger the alert, but not the location.

Comment: It's also not possible with a Jquery event. A user have to click manually at the button. All location starts like "whatsapp://", "intent://" e.g. will not work without a manually click. Only "https://" will work.